# Add more storage space to guest OS on VirtualBox 6

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, virtualbox, storage

I'm using *VirtualBox 6* on *Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS*. I need to add more storage space to the *guest OS*.
I already ran `VBoxManage modifyhd box-disk002.vdi --resize 46080` but the old value remains.
Below is a screenshot of the settings. I tried to use the slider to increase the disk size but that didn't work either.
[image]

How to add more storage space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll recommend to run this command again

```
vboxmanage modifyhd --resize 46080 box-disk002.vdi
```

and then resize file-system by booting VM from some LiveCD with `gparted`.

---

References:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi

Comment: I ran the command again but the "guest OS" still uses the default value. (even if the new value of 46080 is shown in the VM)  Is there a way to do use "resize file-system"  without booting from a LiveCD?

Comment: For me booting from livecd looks the most straight-forward.

Comment: I'm struggling to get it to work. Is it possible to increase the default disc size in VirtualBox for new VMs? (I just need like 10GB more)

Answer (score 3):

Guest OS: **Linux Ubuntu 20.04**

I am more comfortable adding a new **.vdi** disk image using the virtual box and then  mount that to the existing Linux guest OS. I read somewhere on a Linux/VM forum  that changing the storage size of the current disk where you have data available can cause issues. I increased my disk space by adding a new vdi disk.

Here is the article I followed. It is very easy to follow.
https://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/add-a-disk-to-an-ubuntu-virtualbox-vm

In my case I didn't install `gksu`. Instead, I used `sudo` in place of `gksudo`. In the article, author is using **vmkd** as hard disk file type. I used **vdi** as hard disk file type. Apart from that, all steps are same

[image: Virtual Box Configuration]

[image: Disk space configured]

Brief outline of the steps:

#### Create a disk file

1. Right click on the VM you want to add a disk to
2. Click **Settings** in the context menu
3. Click **Storage** in the left sidebar
4. Click **Controller: SATA** and click on the **+** icon
5. Click **Create new disk** in the pop up menu
6. Select disk type in the dialog (I chose VDI)
7. Click on **Dynamically** allocated in the size dialog and click **Next**
8. Name the disk, select a size and click **Next**
9. Click **OK**
10. Note which SATA port the disk is on (for example "Sata port 2")
11. Click **Start** to start the VM

#### Partition in Ubuntu

1. In Ubuntu, open a terminal and identify the disk from the output of

   ```
   dmesg | grep sd
   ```

   You will see a disk that matches the size of the one you created. For example it may be `/dev/sdc`
2. Install gparted (run `sudo apt install gparted) and run` sudo gparted`
3. Click the device (`/dev/sda`) in the top corner and switch to the disk you identified (for example `/dev/sdc`
4. Click **Device** and then **Create Partition Table**
5. Leave as msdos and click **Apply**
6. Click the create new partition icon (top left)
7. Leave everything as is and click **Add**
8. Click the green check mark to apply all operations
9. Click **Apply** in the popup and *Close** when successfully completed

#### Mounting the disk

1. Create a mount point (`hdd2` is just an example name - change if you prefer something else)

   ```
   sudo mkdir /hdd2
   ```
2. Add a line to `/etc/fstab` to mount the new partition on boot

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   Add this line

   ```
   /dev/sdc1    /hdd2    ext4    defaults    0    0
   ```
3. Save, exit and restart the VM.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks Zanna for editing.

Comment: A couple of warnings. First when you create your new disk if you choose a size that even just a bit different than any other disk you have it will make life easier in step 1 of "Partition in Ubuntu". Secondly in that same step you will see "[sdb]", "[sdc]" etc. When you get to step 2 of "Mounting the disk" if you saw, for instance, "[sdc]" in that output you will need to use "/dev/sdc1" at the start of the line you add but, perhaps obviously, if you saw "[sdd]" then you will need to use "/dev/sdd1".

Comment: Another thing I think is worth saying (bearing in mind that I'm no expert) as Muhammad mentions this answer is based on this blog post https://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/add-a-disk-to-an-ubuntu-virtualbox-vm and there are are one or two things at the end of the blog post which aren't mentioned here. I'm not even sure what the significance of them are but I think it would be worthwhile taking a look at them if you thinking of following this answer. No disrespect intended to this answer which does a good job of making the approach visible.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [site](https://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/)

Running Virtual Box 6.1.

When LOGGED OFF from your VM. You just go to File -> Virtual Media Manager -> Choose you VDI and upgrade.[image]