# Cannot Umount the file /dev/sda1 in VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage, memory-usage, disk-image

I am using a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on VirtualBox and start working on Yocto Project.

I was able to modify and allocate until 1TiB in the Virtual box outside but when booting the system, it will just receive the old value (which is 30GB).

I install the `gparted` for partializing but the `/dev/sda1` is kept 30Gb (27.6 GB) as maximum memory storage (It is mounted).

I have try `sudo umount -l /dev/sda1` but it crash the whole system. (I have already take a snap shot )

How can I umount it.Please help. Thank you very much !

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After I installed and boot a bootable live ISO that contains Gparted, I can umounted it. However, the maximum size seem to remain old values.

How can I change it ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add more storage space to guest OS on VirtualBox 6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192735/add-more-storage-space-to-guest-os-on-virtualbox-6)

Comment: @ajgringo619 I was able to change virtual machine disk memory but when come into  partitioning disk space, it will still the same old value. Especially I cannot umount the `/dev/sda1` since it remain its old value as maximum dis image

Comment: @ajgringo619 I have edited my question ! Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Just like with any other Linux system, you can't unmount filesystems in use. You will need to download a bootable live ISO that contains **Gparted** (might as well get it from the source: https://gparted.org/) and force your VM to boot from it. This will allow you to resize the `/dev/sda` partition and gain you the space you increased the VDI by.

Comment: I see. Will those data in old ISO disk image retained if I boot whole new system from new live disk and after that subtitute the old disk image. If not I have to back up by external drive ?

Comment: I don't understand. *Data in an ISO disk image* - can you explain, please? If you're talking about the VM disk image, you should ALWAYS make a backup before doing something like this.

Comment: I mean do I have to reject my old iso file and boot the system to run from new live ISO as you said (I have found this `Download gparted-live-1.1.0-5-amd64.iso`
form [link](https://gparted.org/)  if it is correct).  So when I subtitute my old iso file, will the data in its remain ? :D

Comment: I can't see a situation where the current ISO would be affected. What does it contain? If it's just another bootable ISO (the one you installed the system with, perhaps), then it's not a problem.

Comment: I have boot from it and able umount. However, the maximum size for `/dev/sda1` could not be change.

Comment: You need to move `/dev/sda2` to the right so that the 100GB free space is next to `/dev/sda1`. Then you will be able to add this to `/dev/sda`.